# Please take it on(as) priority.

Tags: prepositional-phrases

What is correct , Is or on in the below sentence-

Please take it on(as) priority.

Most of the places i saw 'as'. Why we can not use 'on' here. Could somebody help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both may work as I found reliable sources mentioning *as* and *on* with the noun *priority*.

But if I dig it further, there's a **subtle** difference -

> Please take it **as** priority - the work itself is priority and I'm least bothered what tasks you may take after my *(this)* instruction. 
>   Please take it **on** priority - I **know** that you already have some tasks but then consider my (this) work **on** priority basis.

Comment: You could also use both words together, don't you think? Parsed like this: (Please take it on)(as priority). In other words, _Please agree to take on this task, and please make it a priority to finish it_.

Comment: @J.R. Yeah, but that *on* is more in context of *take it* whereas I focused on the word *priority*. I checked it here. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+it+on

Answer (score 1):

Most native English speakers would say:

> Please take it on as a priority.

(meaning as a priority task)